# What is _app_start in firebase performance actually measuring?

Tags: android, firebase-performance

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/app-start-foreground-background-traces?platform=android#app-start), the measurement of `_app_start`

- Starts when the app's FirebasePerfProvider ContentProvider completes its onCreate method.
- Stops when the first activity's `onResume()` method is called.

My app has two activities

- LoginActivity
- MainActivity

`LoginActivity` being the launcher activity.

In the `onCreate` method of `LoginActivity`, I check if the user is logged in and open `MainActivity` if true.

My expectation was that the measurement of `_app_start` should stop when the `onResume` of `LoginActivity` is called. (as this is the first activity)

However, I am having trouble understanding these logs (starting the app for a logged in user).

[image]

[image]

The first log shows that `LoginActivity` was rendered in 620ms, but the `_experiment_app_start_ttid` records 1988ms.

Additional Info: I am manually logging the `app_start` event in firebase analytics from `MainActivity`.

Following are my doubts

1. Why is the value of the `Displayed` log(620ms) different from `_experiment_app_start_ttid` (1988ms)? Is this trace something entirely different from `_app_start`?
2. How can I log the value for `_app_start` trace?
3. Does manually logging the `app_start` analytics event in `MainActivity` affect the `_app_start` trace measurement? (like is it stopping after the `onResume` of `MainActivity`?)